# Recuperar carrinho de compras após fechar e abrir o navegador

Tags: java, jsf-2.2, jpa-2.0

Estou montando um carrinho de compras com JSF ele está funcionando, mas não da forma que acredito ser o correto.

**Exemplo:**
Quando entro em sites de vendas, mesmo não estando logada, consigo adicionar itens no carrinho, e mesmo fechando e abrindo o navegador esses itens permanecem lá. No meu caso, quando saio do navegador e entro novamente os itens não permanecem, pois a sessão muda quando o navegador é fechado, nesse caso, é inútil gravar a sessão em itens para recuperá-la quando o usuário retorna ao site. Já pesquisei o uso de *cookies* para esse caso, mas em nada me ajudou. Alguém poderia me ajudar informando como poderia implementar essa situação? Se é implementado usando *cookies* e sessão mesmo?

Estou usando JSF, JPA. Qualquer ajuda ficarei muito grata!

Comment: Sim, salva no cookie alguma informação para você recupere o carrinho de compras.. claro que você deve salvá-lo do lado server também

Comment: Tentei fazer um exemplo usando JSESSIONID, se não saio do navegador ele funciona bem, olha a saída:  Session Id = D5913F3F699B66B8AFEDD32E108F9C92 //nova
JSESSIONID cookie = F688E7A616018963013062251D16A805 //sessão anterior, mas quando fecho o navegador e abro novamente ele ignora a sessão anterior olha o que sai: Session Id = 944D48C7F4BE1F807B207CC9694A629E
JSESSIONID cookie = 944D48C7F4BE1F807B207CC9694A629E Nesse caso é um teste que estou fazendo, será se o problema é porque nesse caso, ainda não salvei essa sessão no servidor?

Comment: Você não vai voltar a sessão anterior, fechou o navegador ela se perdeu, você vai iniciar uma nova sessão. Seu cookie pode ter alguma informação que identifique o usuário, um token, id, etc, dai você inicia uma nova sessão... claro que o carrinho precisa estar salvo do lado server pra poder recuperar. Você pode usar um banco *nosql* como MongoDB para salvar o carrinho, e quando efetivar salvar no seu banco transacional

Comment: Quando o usuário esta logado não tenho esse problema, pois salvo o item com a identificação do usuário, o problema é quando o usuário não esta logado. Seria correto fazer essa identificação por ip?

Comment: Nesse caso você poderia gerar um identificador temporário enquanto não está logado. IP não é uma boa ideia porque se ele estiver atrás de um proxy, você pode acabar lendo somente o IP do proxy da empresa por exemplo, e se mais de um usuário da mesma empresa acessar o site, vai ter o mesmo IP, o que vai ser um problema (todos vão ver o mesmo carrinho)

Comment: Pensei a mesma coisa, realmente ip não é uma boa idéia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sessão só pode guardar atributos enquanto o cliente estiver interagindo com sua aplicação, dentro do período de validade daquela sessão. Em caso de inatividade por um período maior do que a validade ou se o usuário fechar o navegador, a sessão é perdida. Você mesma já constatou isso, verificando 2 JSESSIONIDs diferentes ao fechar e abrir novamente o navegador.

Portanto, se você usar apenas a sessão para manter o estado, não conseguirá resolver o seu problema.

Para identificar unicamente o cliente, uma boa opção seria usar um cookie mesmo. O cookie é persistido no próprio navegador do cliente, geralmente em um arquivo texto, durante a validade que você especificar.

Nesse caso, você precisaria definir um cookie específico para sua finalidade. O seu código teria que salvar os itens do carrinho em um banco de dados e atribuir um ID único a esse conjunto de itens salvos. Você poderia aproveitar o próprio JSESSIONID, se você não quiser gerar uma String aleatória. Lembre-se de atualizar o banco de dados cada vez que o usuário modificar algo no carrinho, colocando ou retirando algum produto.

O cookie seria criado e enviado ao navegador, tendo como conteúdo aquele ID único. Ajuste a validade do cookie de acordo com seu requisito de negócio. Ficaria parecido com isso:

```
String valorCookieCarrinho = ID; //O que você quiser definir, basta ser único
Cookie cookieCarrinho = new Cookie("cookieCarrinho_br.com.seusite", valorCookieCarrinho);
cookieCarrinho.setMaxAge(60*60*24*7); //Defina a validade - 1 semana?
response.addCookie(cookieCarrinho);
```

Em cada visita ao site, **para a qual ainda não exista um carrinho ativo** você procura o cookie, obtém o ID e busca os itens correspondentes no banco de dados. Caso eles existam, você coloca eles no carrinho que está na sessão. É importante verificar primeiro, para não correr o risco de sobrescrever um carrinho atualizado.

```
Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();

if (cookies != null) {
 for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
   if (cookie.getName().equals("cookieCarrinho_br.com.seusite")) {
     //pegar o valor do ID com cookie.getValue() e buscar no bd
    }
  }
}
```

Não se esqueça de fazer o banco de dados expurgar os registros abandonados. Para isso, guarde a data em cada registro de carrinho.

Comment: Olá Guilherme, muito obrigada pela resposta e pelo seus exemplos. Então meu problema é que mesmo criando um cookie com uma identificação eu não tenho como saber se um usuário não logado é o mesmo que entrou no sistema adicionou itens no carrinho e por algum motivo, perdeu a sessão retornou ao site e perdeu tudo que já tinha inserido. Fiz de um jeito que não sei se é correto, mas foi a forma que encontrei, estou identificando o usuário não logado pelo ip "externo" e estou salvando essa informação como id, na hora que qualquer pessoal entra no carrinho busco se possui dados por IP.

Comment: Dessa forma, fiz alguns teste e esta respondendo bem, um problema é que o IP sofre alterações de vez em quando, de ontem pra hoje o meu já mudou duas vezes, mas por os itens ficar no carrinho por um determinado tempo, o risco não é tão ruim.

Comment: Pelo IP realmente não é a melhor maneira. Principalmente porque vários clientes podem ter o mesmo IP. No caso da rede de uma empresa, por exemplo, geralmente há um proxy que fica na saída para a internet com o chamado “IP de borda”.

Comment: O cookie deveria funcionar, usando um ID único, como expliquei. Edite a resposta e descreva melhor o que você fez. Em que momento está *setando* o cookie? Em que momento está recuperando seu valor? Lembre-se que a sessão nunca será a mesma. Não adianta tentar buscar dados na nova sessão.

Comment: Olá Guilherme, estudei mais um pouco a situação e implementei com cookie, segui a sua ideia mas implementei usando a biblioteca do Ominifaces. Muito obrigada!